# sqlalchemy session.close() not closing connection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How session is able to output user objects even after session.close() is executed ?

**__init__**.py

```
 def get_db(request):
    maker = request.registry.dbmaker
    session = maker()

    def cleanup(request):
        if request.exception is not None:
            session.rollback()
        else:
            session.commit()
        session.close()

    request.add_finished_callback(cleanup)
    return session
```

view.py

```
@view_config(route_name='get_path', renderer='json')
def get_path(request):
    session = request.db
    session.query(User).all()   # outputs user objects
    session.close()
    session.query(User).all()   # outputs user objects
```

Even i tried `session.bind.dispose()` (should dispose all connections)

Answer (score 3):

When you run `session.close()` it releases all the resources it might have used, i.e. transactional/connection. It does not physically close the session so that no other queries can be run after you have called it...

From [sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#closing):

> **Closing**
>
> The close() method issues a expunge_all(), and releases any transactional/connection resources. When connections are returned to the connection pool, transactional state is rolled back as well.

So it would still run the query after you called `session.close()`. Any uncommitted transactions, as stated above, will be rolled back.